# SSIS Flat File Text Qualifier

Tags: ssis

I have a flat file connection which loads a text file in an SSIS package.  Visual Studio insists on sometimes adding a  text qualifier on the connection manager, even though I delete it.  When this text qualifier is added, the last record in the file is skipped so this causes problems.  I need a way of ensuring that the files work always, with or without this  qualifier.  Since I am creating these files programatically, how does it need to end so that the  qualifier doesn't impact it?  I tried ending the file with \r\n but it didn't seem to solve the issue.

Comment: Can you add some sample of rows in the file?

Comment: Could you help me understand "Visual Studio insists on sometimes adding a text qualifier on the connection manager" I've not experienced this before. What qualifier is it adding? What is the definition of your flat file? `\r\n` is not going to be valid for qualifiers in SSIS lingo, it will be CRLF.

Comment: I remove (clear) the text qualifier field and save. If i then modify the connection manager (eg add a column) on save it adds "<none>" in the qualifier field.  If i forget to remove it manually again, then I have an issue.  The file is a pipe delimited text file

Comment: It sounds to me like your row terminator for your last row is the problem, and you are debugging up the wrong tree.  However we won't know without some sample data.

Answer (score 1):

If you edit the text qualifier out using the properties flyout tab on the right just by clicking on the task once... it should stay gone until you edit the connection again... then it will come back and you will have to do that once again.

It seems to be a issue when editing the connection using the editor.

See below:

[image: Example]